# Javascript - odd and even numbers can't work synchronous on my code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```js
let num = prompt("Number");
for (let i = 0; i < num; num--) {
  if (num % 2 == 0) {
    console.log(num);
  }
}

// ******* not running ??? ***********
num = "";
for (let i = 0; i < num; num--) {
  if (num % 2 !== 0) {
    console.log(num);
  }
}
```

my objective is:1 . to enter a number in prompt
2.to show all even and odd numbers up to the entered number.
idk. why second part !== is not working

for the ideal mode I was wondering if it is possible to enter a loop in array.

to have something like that:

Prompt (for exemple:50)
evenNumber = [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10... ]
oddNumber = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9...]

Comment: Why post an image and waste silica when you could have simply copy pasted the code into your question? Also, it's easier to answer using a snippet then copying characters from an image in order to help. Please... take a [tour], read [ask]. Then [edit] with a [mcve]

Comment: Instead of making a second if case in a second loop, just use else in the same loop and then the console.log statement. If you want to add them to an array, initialise one by doing var name = []; and then before the console.log statement in the loop add a name.push(num);

Comment: Why would you want arrays of odd and even numbers? Where is `0`? You could use simply `return !(num % 2);`  with only one function...?

Comment: After `num` gets reduced to zero via `num--` in the first loop, then `let i = 0; i < num` will never be true in the second loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short way of doing it:

```js
function evenOdd(n){
 const evenodd=[[],[]];
 for (let i=0; i<n; i++) evenodd[i%2].push(i)
 return evenodd;
}

const [even,odd]=evenOdd(prompt("Generate even and odd numbers up to:"));

console.log("even numbers:",even);
console.log("odd numbers:",odd);
```